# Why can't I call a template base class constructor with a const_iterator?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, const-iterator

For some reason, the following code gives the error `Symbol 'TemplateBase' could not be resolved.`:

```
template <typename T>
class TemplateBase
{
    TemplateBase(std::map<std::string, T>::const_iterator anIterator)
    { }
};

class SubClass : public TemplateBase<int>
{
    SubClass(std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator anIterator) :
        TemplateBase<int>(anIterator) //Error: Symbol 'TemplateBase' could not be resolved.
    { }
};
```

Strangely, no error appears when I remove the `::const_iterator` and only `std::map<std::string, int>` remains:

```
template <typename T>
class TemplateBase
{
    TemplateBase(std::map<std::string, T> aMap)
    { }
};

class SubClass : public TemplateBase<int>
{
    SubClass(std::map<std::string, int> aMap) :
        TemplateBase<int>(aMap) //No error.
    { }
};
```

Additionally, the following function gives no error either, so it really seems related to the combination of a template base class call with a const_iterator:

```
void function()
{
    std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator anIterator;
    TemplateBase<int> aTemplateBase(anIterator); //No error
}
```

Is there some rule against using const_iterator as an argument for base class template constructors that I'm unaware of? Or is this a compiler bug?

I'm compiling with MinGW 64bit 4.9.0 on Windows 7, using C++11.

Comment: You're missing `typename`.

Comment: "an error"? Which one?

Comment: @Igvidal: "Error: Symbol 'TemplateBase' could not be resolved.", it's in a comment in the code fragment. I've added it to the main text as well now.

Comment: @ildjarn: The problem persists when <class T>  is replaced by <typename T>. Also, in my actual code I was using a class. I've edited the question's code.

Comment: That's not the one I meant. @Adam has it right.

Comment: @ildjarn: Ah, okay, I didn't even know it was possible to place typename there.

Comment: @Aberrant : Not only possible, but required! ;-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a nested type that depends on a template type you need to use the `typename` keyword:

```
TemplateBase(typename std::map<std::string, T>::const_iterator anIterator)
{ }
```

Comment: Huh, didn't expect it was even legal to put the word typename there. This fixed it for me, thanks. But why is this necessary for `std::map<std::string, T>::const_iterator` and not for `std::map<std::string, T>`?

Comment: @Aberrant Because you're not referring to a nested type in the second case. Also, do you feel [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords?rq=1) is a duplicate of your question? My close vote is binding, so I want to check with you before I do that.

Comment: @Praetorian I guess it probably is. I can't find this specific syntax in there (`ClassName(typename someComplexlyDerivedNestedIdontevenType)`) but judging by how extensive the keyword is explained, it is probably in there in a way. I'll make sure to read the whole thing thoroughly. So yeah, closing this question is fine, I suppose.

Comment: To explain, without the `typename` keyword the compiler can't tell whether `const_iterator` is a typename or a variable name. You might write a template specialization of `std::map` after this that changes that detail.

Comment: @Aberrant : See this FAQ for more information on `typename`: [What is the template `typename` keyword used for?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename)